# how to save the output for next algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I tokenize a text file and want to use the array of words i got from the print function for lemmatizing the splited words how can i continue lemmatizing those words?

```
 for file in glob.glob ('*.txt):
    for line in open(file):
        print(line.split(),end= '')
```

```
['Widely', 'annexed', 'working', 'Spoken', 'languages' ] 
['confused','inhabit', 'languages']
['communities', 'includes', 'parts']
```

Comment: you mean how to capture the data into a data structure?

Comment: yes i got those arrays as a result of the splititng and now i want to lemmatize all the words